# Integrate Firebase with 3rd party API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to integrate my firebase project with some 3rd party API's, like the twitter API.

**3rd party API**

The following code will listen to new tweets containing the certain text 'little rocket man':

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

// setup new twitter client
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});

// open new twitter stream
let stream = this.client.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'little rocket man' });

stream.on('data', (event: any) => {
  let tweetText = event && event.text; // this should be written to the firebase db
});
```

**Firebase Cloud Functions**

The following firebase cloud functions listens to incoming HTTP GET requests on a specific route and saves data back to the firebase db:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'; // Firebase Admin SDK

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// this example uses a HTTP trigger, but how can I trigger it whenever new tweets containint 'little rocket man' are detected??
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const original = req.query.text;

  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
```

**Question**

How can I write the tweets I'm recieving from the twitter client back to the firebase db? If possible, I'd like to run all the code on firebase cloud functions.

**Disclaimer:**
I'm new to firebase and although googling around for a few hours I wasn't able to find the solution to my problem on the net. I'd like to apologize in advance, should I have overseen it.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you intend to run the first bit of code in Cloud Functions, or if its running elsewhere.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry, yes I intend to run everything on firebase cloud functions, if this is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can't use streaming APIs like this in Cloud Functions.  A function may only respond to some distinct event, such as an HTTP request, or some change in your database.  Functions can't run indefinitely.

If you want to collect tweets that match some query into your database, you can use IFTTT to periodically send them to a function as they become available.  I recently finished [a small project](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/d61cbe63b3a2f90799d9651451adfcfa) that does exactly that.

Comment: mh I see..
the twitter thing was just a simplified example actually.. so you advice to create IFTTT triggers for each api I want to integrate, right?

Comment: Or whatever service will give you a webhook to receive the data you want.